# N-gram Language Model returns nothing

Tags: python, dictionary, prediction, n-gram, language-model

I am following the tutorial here: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/08/comprehensive-guide-language-model-nlp-python-code/#h2_5 to create a Language model. I am following the bit about the N-gram Language model.

This is the completed code:

```py
from nltk.corpus import reuters
from nltk import bigrams, trigrams
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

# Create a placeholder for model
model = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: 0))

# Count frequency of co-occurance
for sentence in reuters.sents():
    for w1, w2, w3 in trigrams(sentence, pad_right=True, pad_left=True):
        model[(w1, w2)][w3] += 1

# Let's transform the counts to probabilities
for w1_w2 in model:
    total_count = float(sum(model[w1_w2].values()))
    for w3 in model[w1_w2]:
        model[w1_w2][w3] /= total_count

input = input("Hi there! Please enter an incomplete sentence and I can help you\
 finish it!\n").lower().split()

print(model[tuple(input)])
```

To get output from the model, the website does this: `print(dict(model["the", "price"]))` but I want to generate output from a user inputted sentence. When I write `print(model[tuple(input)])`, it gives me an empty defaultdict.

Disregard this (keeping for history):

> How do I give it the list I create from the input? `model` is a
> dictionary and I've read that using a list as a key isn't a good idea
> but that's exactly what they're doing? And I'm assuming mine doesn't
> work because I'm listing a list? Would I have to iterate through the
> words to get results?
>
> As a side note, is this model considering the sentence as a whole to
> predict the next word, or just the *last* word?

Comment: 1. the dictionary is using tuples, not lists (see `model[(w1, w2)][w3]...`.  2. From the call to `trigrams` I can only conclude that it uses trigrams, i.e.: computes the probability of a word given the occurrence of the 2 previous ones.

Comment: @JuanR I totally missed that it was using tuples! And yes, trigram would suggest that as well. Thank you for pointing all that out!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to give the model the last two words from the list not the entire thing, even if it's two words. Like so:

```
model[tuple(input[-2:])]
```